# Merge user-names in Git repository commits?

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I change the author of a commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git)

I noticed that on GitHub, pushing from terminal gives the correct specified name. However, editing in the GitHub online "edit" feature gives your username to new commits. Add to this the fact that some commits have my old username on another repository, and it makes quite a mess. Is there any way to merge usernames, or at least set it to use the same username when using the online editor?

Comment: You can alias your old name to your new name on github

Comment: Where? Can you link to the page?

Answer (score 2):

Correct the setting in GitHub so it matches what you have on your machine.

If you want, rewrite the history with filter-branch for consistency.